# Getting the latest date from a id

Tags: sql-server-2008

I run the above sql statement and i got this.[IMG]http://i1093.photobucket.com/albums/i422/walkgirl_1993/asd-1_zps5506632e.jpg[/IMG] i'm trying display the latest date which you can see the 3 and 4. For caseid 3, it should display the latest row which is the 2012-12-20 16:12:36.000. I tried using group by, order by. Google some website said to use rank but i'm not sure about the rank as i dont really get rank. Some suggestions?

```
select [Case].CaseID, Agent.AgentName, Assignment.Description, A.AgentName as EditedBy, A.DateEdited from Agent inner join [Case-Agent] on [Case-Agent].AgentID = Agent.AgentID inner join [Assignment] on Assignment.AssignmentID = [Case-Agent].AssignmentID inner join [Case] on [Case].CaseID = [Case-Agent].CaseID inner join (select EditedCase.CaseID, [EditedCase].DateEdited, [Agent].AgentName from EditedCase inner join [Agent] on [Agent].AgentID = [EditedCase].AgentID) A on A.CaseID = [Case].CaseID where [Assignment].AssignmentID = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it using RANK you just need to add the RANK to the subquery and get to rank the DateEdited for each CaseID and Agent and then in the main query put a WHERE clause to only select rows where the rank is 1. I think I have got the partition clause right - its a bit hard without seeing your data.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
  [Case].CaseID 
  ,Agent.AgentName 
  ,Assignment.Description 
  ,A.AgentName AS EditedBy 
  ,A.DateEdited 
FROM Agent 
  INNER JOIN [Case-Agent] ON [Case-Agent].AgentID = Agent.AgentID 
  INNER JOIN [Assignment] ON Assignment.AssignmentID = [Case-Agent].AssignmentID 
  INNER JOIN [Case] ON [Case].CaseID = [Case-Agent].CaseID 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                EditedCase.CaseID 
                ,[EditedCase].DateEdited 
                ,[Agent].AgentName
                ,RANK ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY EditedCase.CaseID, [Agent].AgentName 
                               ORDER BY [EditedCase].DateEdited DESC ) AS pos
              FROM EditedCase 
                INNER JOIN [Agent] on [Agent].AgentID = [EditedCase].AgentID) A on A.CaseID = [Case].CaseID 
WHERE [Assignment].AssignmentID = 0 
  AND pos = 1
```

You could also change the sub query into an aggregate query that brings back the MAX date like this:

```
SELECT 
  [Case].CaseID 
  ,Agent.AgentName 
  ,Assignment.Description 
  ,A.AgentName AS EditedBy 
  ,A.DateEdited 
FROM Agent 
  INNER JOIN [Case-Agent] ON [Case-Agent].AgentID = Agent.AgentID 
  INNER JOIN [Assignment] ON Assignment.AssignmentID = [Case-Agent].AssignmentID 
  INNER JOIN [Case] ON [Case].CaseID = [Case-Agent].CaseID 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                EditedCase.CaseID 
                ,MAX([EditedCase].DateEdited) AS DateEdited 
                ,[Agent].AgentName
              FROM EditedCase 
                INNER JOIN [Agent] on [Agent].AgentID = [EditedCase].AgentID
              GROUP BY
                EditedCase.CaseID
                ,[Agent].AgentName) A on A.CaseID = [Case].CaseID 
WHERE [Assignment].AssignmentID = 0 
  AND pos = 1
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It actually works! But i dont still get the idea of rank though

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track; you need to use a ranking function here, for example `row_number()`:

```
with LatestCase as
(
  select [Case].CaseID
    , Agent.AgentName
    , Assignment.Description
    , A.AgentName as EditedBy
    , A.DateEdited
    , caseRank = row_number() over (partition by [Case].CaseID order by A.DateEdited desc)
  from Agent
    inner join [Case-Agent] on [Case-Agent].AgentID = Agent.AgentID
    inner join [Assignment] on Assignment.AssignmentID = [Case-Agent].AssignmentID
    inner join [Case] on [Case].CaseID = [Case-Agent].CaseID
    inner join
    (
      select EditedCase.CaseID
        , [EditedCase].DateEdited
        , [Agent].AgentName
      from EditedCase
        inner join [Agent] on [Agent].AgentID = [EditedCase].AgentID
    ) A on A.CaseID = [Case].CaseID where [Assignment].AssignmentID = 0
)
select *
from LatestCase
where caseRank = 1
```